# Obtain Ids from List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Im getting a List of customer Ids which are held in a `List<string>`.
I am then retrieving customers from my database which are held in `List<Customer>`

I would like to get a List of customer Ids which are not in my database but are in the customer string list so i can delete them. So

if `List<string> ThirdpartyList` has the data:

```
Record 1: 1234
Record 2: 1235
Record 3: 1236
Record 4: 1237
```

and my db list `List<Customer>` CustsFromDatabase has

```
Record 1: 1234
Record 2: 2345
Record 3: 2346
Record 4: 1237
```

The the list returned should be

```
1235
1236
```

As those records are no longer required. I have tried the LINQ `Except` method and `Any` methods but didn't get the results i need.

Comment: Then show us the code you used for `Except`.

Comment: Show your efforts in trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Id is string, get Ids withs way:

```
var idsToDelete = ThirdpartyList.Where(s=>!CustsFromDatabase.Any(x=>x.Id == s))
```

otherwise, you should compare strings

```
x.Id.ToString() == s
```

If somebody, who downvoted, explained, what is wrong, i could improove my answer.

Comment: Thank you - i noticed what i done wrong and your code worked!